# Can I identify a string on which cursor is placed in Java?

Tags: java, events, mouselistener

Currently I'm working on a Java Project. But to do this I want to read string from cursor i.e. I want to read string on which cursor is currently placed. How can I do this?

Comment: Please provide sample code which shows what you have tried yourself

Comment: Actually I couldn't  start my project because of this problem. Actually, I don't know how to do this specific job.

Comment: What strings did you want to be able to read?  For example, do you want to display some strings in your app's window and then be able to detect when the user clicks on one of them?

Comment: Actually , there will be some words on screen then if I place cursor under any word then cursor will read that word and return me that word....

Comment: @Evan - `Actually , there will be some words on screen...` - By your last comment, you've taken something relatively simple to something relatively complex. What does that mean anyways? Do you mean some words in any arbitrary application? Or, do you mean in your own application within perhaps a JTextArea or JEditPane?

Comment: I mean some words in any arbitrary application or any blog.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear where exactly you are placing your text caret (cursor). The example methods below assumes that the cursor is placed upon a word contained within text displayed within a Swing Text Component like a **JTextField**, **JTextArea**, **JEditPane**, etc that is made viewable within your **own** application project. The [javax.swing.text.Utilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Utilities.html) class can get the data you want.

```
public static String getWordAtCaret(JTextComponent tc) {
    String res = null;
    try {
        int caretPosition = tc.getCaretPosition();
        int startIndex = Utilities.getWordStart(tc, caretPosition);
        int endIndex = Utilities.getWordEnd(tc, caretPosition);
        res = tc.getText(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
    }
    catch (BadLocationException ex) {
        // Purposely Ignore so as to return null.
        // Do what you want with the exception if you like.
    }
    return res;
}

public static String getNextWordFromCaret(JTextComponent tc) {
    String res = null;
    try {
        int caretPosition = Utilities.getNextWord(tc, tc.getCaretPosition());
        int startIndex = Utilities.getWordStart(tc, caretPosition);
        int endIndex = Utilities.getWordEnd(tc, caretPosition);
        res = tc.getText(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
    }
    catch (BadLocationException ex) {
        // Purposely Ignore so as to return null.
        // Do what you want with the exception if you like.
    }
    return res;
}

public static String getPreviousWordFromCaret(JTextComponent tc) {
    String res = null;
    try {
        int caretPosition = Utilities.getPreviousWord(tc, tc.getCaretPosition()) - 2;
        int startIndex = Utilities.getWordStart(tc, caretPosition);
        int endIndex = Utilities.getWordEnd(tc, caretPosition);
        res = tc.getText(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
    }
    catch (BadLocationException ex) {
        // Purposely Ignore so as to return null.
        // Do what you want with the exception if you like.
    }
    return res;
}
```

**Note:** Punctuation attached to a particular word can provide unexpected results when using the getNextWordFromCaret() or getPreviousWordFromCaret() methods. Punctuation like the period (**.**) could be considered a word with either of these methods and therefore some consideration must be given to prevent it.

Comment: I want to develop a Java application which will translate any word on which a cursor will be placed. If  I run my application on background only then the cursor will play this role of translation. So I want to read string using cursor.